# How to use URL Rewrite in IIS to point to application in Apache Tomcat

Tags: web, iis, tomcat9, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to setup URL Rewrite in IIS so that an application I've deployed in Tomcat displays when I browse to http://localhost/

I've managed to get it to point to the Tomcat homepage with the following URL Rewrite settings

[URL Rewrite v1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5LSj.png)

As soon as I add the application path to the rewrite URL, I get an error...

[URL Rewrite v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkpcD.png)

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/httpplatformhandler/info Microsoft created HttpPlatformHandler to bridge IIS and Java, so you shouldn't turn to something else.

Comment: Please post your rewrite rules, otherwise it is impossible to know the cause of the problem, or you can use the failed request trace to see detailed error information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.